# Mouseout Not Working After InnerHtml Changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Could anybody explain to me why

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $("#fitness").mouseenter(function() {
  $("#fitness .cont").html(jQuery('#fitness_content').html());  
}).mouseleave(function(){
  $("#fitness .cont").html(jQuery('#fitness_img').html());
  }) 
});
```

is not working. The mouseout or mouseleave event doesn't seem to get caught. Has it got something to do with the size of the DIV? I tried using live and bind and it wasn't working either. The only case it worked was when I update the img src directly using attr method. However I would like to be able to wrap the image in some DIV. Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/donysukardi/CnWku/. Any help is greatly appreciated!I

Answer (score 0):

Because all of the elements that go inside the `.cont` element, are absolutely positioned. This makes the actual container to be of zero height so there is nothing to catch the event..

if you put a border to the container you will see what i mean..

Remove the absolute positions to all elements except the container seems to do the trick..

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/CnWku/2/

Comment: hi Gaby.. Thanks for the reply. I also thought that was the problem. But removing absolute doesn't solve the problem. The mouseout event does get caught sometimes, but not always

Comment: @donysukardi, if you could describe how you want the page to work, we could find an alternative way to accomplish it .. Do you have to use absolute positioning at all ? (*even for the outer div ?*)

Comment: Let's say I want to have a DIV with an image inside and I would like to change the image on hover. But the problem is the two images are of different heights. And I want the DIV to grow taller relative to the current position, hence the bottom position 0